# ingress always showing default backend - 404

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to install the Cyclos Mobile app on GCP using the demo given on youtube on this URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmfdhOXK_ik

Everything setup perfectly as per this video but when I am trying to access the setup on browser it always showing `default backend - 404`. I have tried everything as per stack overflow several previous questions but still same error.

Any I idea to fix this ?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencypt-staging
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer":"letsencypt-staging","kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout":"3600"},"name":"cyclos-ingress-nginx-https","namespace":"cyclos-name-space"},"spec":{"backend":{"serviceName":"default-http-backend","servicePort":80},"rules":[{"host":"ip-address.xip.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"cyclos-app-stateful","servicePort":80},"path":"/*"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["ip-address.xip.io"],"secretName":"ip-address.xip.io-tls-secret"}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2020-09-29T07:00:01Z"
  generation: 11
  name: cyclos-ingress-nginx-https
  namespace: cyclos-name-space
  resourceVersion: "643221534"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/cyclos-name-space/ingresses/cyclos-ingress-nginx-https
  uid: uid
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: ip-address.xip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: cyclos-app-stateful
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ip-address.xip.io
    secretName: ip-address.xip.io-tls-secret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: IP
```

Comment: How are you testing? From your browser? If so, with which URL? If not, how?

Comment: Remove `*` from `path: /*`. Does it work after you remove it?

Comment: I have tried but still not working after removing *

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere ip-address.xip.io using this url in browser. as ingress shows in console.

Comment: @Matt ```503 Service Temporarily Unavailable. nginx/1.19.1``` showing after removing *

Comment: Are you sure that thecuclos container is working? Can you curl it from the inside?

Comment: It is not showing any error though green tick showing on everything. how can I do that just ```curl container``` ?

Comment: Use kubectl to exec to container or create a new one and exec to it. You also need to find internal IP (*cluster ip*) of a cyclos pod, and then run `curl <cyclos-cluster-ip>:<port>` from the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222299/discussion-between-mukesh-kumar-sharma-and-matt).

Comment: @Matt when I tried to curl container it is showing timeout.

Comment: So most probably this is the issue. Check if port is open and if you are curling correct port. If this doeasn't helps try curling sth different, maybe its networking(CNI) problem.

Comment: I tried to setup a demo as per https://medium.com/bluekiri/deploy-a-nginx-ingress-and-a-certitificate-manager-controller-on-gke-using-helm-3-8e2802b979ec and it's working fine with same config.